# Oil leak after oil change

Tags: oil, oil-change, oil-leak

Had my oil changed, went home, went back outside later, and found a puddle of oil under my truck. I called the shop and they said bring it back again. Then they told me that someone had put an oversized bolt on the oil pan drain plug and don't keep the correct one in stock. However, I messed with it again and got the truck home.

Should I take it back to them? If that was the case shouldn't they have said something when they took the old plug out of the oil pan? And are they responsible to fix the leak?

Comment: I don't think going back to the shop with no oil in the engine is a good idea, and they are 100% responsible for this, they should have a guy come with the bolt and oil to your house

Comment: How much oil is leaking? What size puddle are we talking about here?

Comment: If someone before that shop installed an over sized plug, it is not their fault it does not seal on the next oil change. Oversized plugs are a patch and do not always work the next time you remove it.

Answer (score 5):

I work in a service centre - either the sump plug was put on finger tight and then the tech forgot to tighten with a socket or he didn't use a collapsible washer or the washer was faulty or depending on how much oil is on your driveway they didn't wash down the sump and the filter area after the service was complete. Either way they totally responsible. Check your oil level if it's too low put it on a tow truck and have them charged for the tow.

Answer (score 3):

Don't drive it. Tell the shop to come to you as it's their mistake. Don't drive the vehicle back unless you know whatever is leaking is safe and won't just fall off, as there's a chance that you may loose the engine oil altogether and that's NOT good.

The shop should come out to you with the correct parts, and oil to top-up again.